# PHP - get random image from multiple folders

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out the best way, using PHP, to pull a random image from multiple sub-folders on my site. I would use the RecursiveDirectoryIterator to iterate through the subfolders and extract images, but am wondering how to handle the randomisation and how to do it efficiently. Any advice on how to go about this?

Comment: I believe u can read file names and directory names, Fill it in a array then use array_rand function http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function get_images($root) {

    $r = array();
    foreach(glob("$root/*") as $n) {
        if (is_dir($n)) {
            $r = array_merge($r, get_images($n));
        } else {
           $r[] = $n;
        }
    }

    return $r;
}

$files = get_images('foo');
shuffle($files);
echo $files[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a random number for the iteration endpoint (while $i < 10). Before this you can create another random session to choose the directory.

---

Read all images into an array then pick a random index.

Answer (score 0):

Load all the full `$path`s into an `$array` and select `mt_rand(0, count($array)-1)`.

You might want to cache your list as long as it does not change, to avoid re-iterating over your directories.